# Password to Join FaceTime Call

Tags: password, facetime

I am conferencing a few friends over FaceTime video in the near future and would like to add a fun feature to the call. I want that as I call my friends and they accept the call, they are greeted with a prompt and must enter a password before joining the call. Does anyone know if such a thing exists? If not, is there a way to implement it myself?

Thanks,
Charles

Answer (score 3):

No, that feature does not exist for FaceTime calls and you could not add a password to a FaceTime call yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt. Are you aware of any other video conferencing software that includes this feature?

Comment: Yes, you can require a password for a WebEx call. However, usually they would call in and then be prompted to enter their password. If you call them, the password is not required.